# How to print my radio buttons in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have questionnaire with four radio buttons and one input type text. Print in sequence without deleting the previous one.

```js
var todos = $('input[type="radio"]');
$(todos).on('click', () => {
  var newText = '';
  Array.from(todos).forEach(
    function(element) {
      if (element.checked)
        newText += element.value
    });
  $('#notem').val(newText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br> SI
<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r1" value='SI PRATICARIA FUTBOL, '> NO
<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r2" value='NO PRACTICARIA FUTBOL, '>
<br><br> NATACION
<br> SI
<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r3" value='SI PRATICARIA NATACION, '> NO
<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r4" value='NO PRATICARIA NATACION, '>
<br><br> CICLISMO
<br> SI
<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r5" value='SI PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '> NO
<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r6" value='NO PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '>
<br><br> LE GUSTARIA PRATICAR OTRO DEPORTE
<br> SI
<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r7" value='SI PRACTICARIA OTRO'> NO
<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r8" value='NO PRACTICARIA OTRO'>
<br>
```

Comment: Its not working , i dont know why

Comment: $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val(), $(this).attr('name'));
});

Comment: you should add input element tag in html like <input type="text" name="notem" id="notem" value=''>